# ¿cómo insertar 3 vectores en una matriz?

Tags: pascal

Necesito ingresar 3 vectores en una matriz. Me quede en la function "cargar" para insertar los vectores. Pero no se de que manera hacerlo.

A continuación mi código:

```
program ejer51;
uses crt;

TYPE
    vtexto = array [1..5] of string;
    ventero = array [1..5] of integer;
    tmatriz = array [1..3,1..5] of string;

VAR
    vApeNom:vtexto;
    vEdad:ventero;
    vAnioCarrera:ventero;
    mAlumnos:tmatriz;

procedure nomApe (var a:vtexto);
var i:integer;
    begin
        for i:=1 to 5 do
            begin
                write('Ingrese nombre y apellido del alumno ',i,': '); readln(a[i]); 
                writeln;
            end;
    end;

procedure edad(var b:ventero);
var i:integer;
    
    begin
        for i:= 1 to 5 do
            begin
                repeat
                    write('Ingrese la edad del alumno numero ',i,': '); readln(b[i]);
                    writeln;
                        if (b[i] < 18) or (b[i] > 80) then
                            writeln('**ERROR** Solo se permiten ingresar edades de mayores de 18 y menores de 80 anios');
                until (b[i] >= 18) and (b[i] <= 80);
            end;
    end;

procedure comienzo(var c:ventero);
var i:integer;
    begin
        for i:= 1 to 5 do
            begin
                repeat
                     write('Ingrese el anio en el que comenzo la carrera, alumno ',i,': '); readln(c[i]);
                        if (c[i] < 2000) or (c[i] > 2018) then
                            writeln('**ERROR** Solo se permiten el ingreso mayores al anio 2000 y menores al 2018');
                until (c[i] >= 2000) and (c[i] <=2018);
            end;
    end;

function cargar(var d:tmatriz;var vApeNom; var vEdad; var vAnioCarrera):string;
var i,j:integer;
    begin
        for i:=1 to 3 do
            for j:=1 to 5 do
                begin
                    d[i,j]:=vApeNom+vEdad+vAnioCarrera;
                end;
        
    end;

begin
    nomApe(vApeNom);
    edad(vEdad);
    comienzo(vAnioCarrera);
    

end.
```

Comment: El código debe ir en la pregunta misma. Insertaste una _no-respuesta_. Además, no olvides mostrar un [repro] _de lo que has intentado_ hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. "No sé cómo hacerlo" no es un buen argumento... Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas en el código:

- Los tipos de datos de los elementos de los vectores no coinciden con el tipo de datos de los elementos de la matriz. Esto puede *solucionarse* haciendo conversiones, que es lo que haré en mi respuesta, aunque no es lo ideal (depende de para qué quieras los datos).
- La firma del procedimiento `cargar` no declara el tipo de los parámetros de los vectores, es mejor trabajar con parámetros tipados, por lo que en mi respuesta declararé los tipos de dato.
- No necesitas iterar por la segunda dimensión de la matriz, lo que generalmente se hace es declarar el índice que corresponde a cada *dato*; en tu caso, nombre, edad y año. Para mayor claridad del código, lo haré declarando constantes para este caso.
- Cómo mapeas los vectores en la matriz es arbitrario, sin embargo lo más común es que el modelo sea sea fila/columna, donde los datos de una misma fila pertenecen a un mismo registro, y los de cada columna a un *campo* dentro de dicho registro. Tú lo estás presentando al revés, no lo cambiaré, pero dado que estoy acostumbrado a seguir esta convención, siento que la cosa está al revés...
- Los parámetros de los vectores no serán modificados dentro de esta rutina, por tanto no los pasaré por variable, sino por constante.

Tomando en cuenta lo dicho, la rutina para *mover* los datos de los vectores a la matriz podría ser algo así:

```
const
  idxNombre = 1;
  idxEdad = 2;
  idxAnio = 3;

procedure cargar(var mAlumno: tmatriz; const vApeNom: vtexto; 
  const vEdad, vAnioCarrera: ventero);
var 
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    mAlumno[idxNombre, I] := vApeNom[I];
    mAlumno[idxEdad, I] := IntToStr(vEdad[I]);
    mAlumno{idxAnio, I] := IntToStr(vAnioCarrera[I]);
  end;
end;
```

El programa principal, entonces, podría quedar así:

```
begin
  nomApe(vApeNom);
  edad(vEdad);
  comienzo(vAnioCarrera);
  cargar(mAlumnos, vApeNom, vEdad, vAnioCarrera);  
  imprimir(mAlumnos);
end.
```

Ojo, me he valido de la función `IntToStr()` para realizar las conversiones de entero a string. Esta debiera estar disponible dentro de la RTL de cualquier compilador moderno de Pascal, si tu compilador no la soporta, ya te tocará investigar y utilizar los mecanismos a tu disposición para realizar la conversión, o bien manejar todo como string.